# Message author name without the hashtag in embed message

Tags: discord, bots

I want my bot when someone says something the bot to say the author's name without hashtag and also the content of the message.

But this embedVar = discord.Embed(title='The', (message.author), 'posted', description=message.content, color=0x0000FF)  doesn't work.

Can you help me please

````
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if str(message.channel) in ['general']:
        if not message.author == client.user:
            embedVar = discord.Embed(title='The', (message.author), 'posted', description=message.content, color=0x0000FF)
            embedVar.set_author(name=message.author)
            embedVar.set_footer(text='Facebook-')
            await message.delete()
            await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.author == client.user:
        await message.channel.send(message.content)
        await client.delete_message(message)
```